# What is the mechanism of water damage to this flex circuit keyboard track?

Tags: repair, fpc

I have a wireless Logitech keyboard which suffered water damage: after it got submerged in water, some keys stopped working. It was very strange to me, since I guessed that if some important element was damaged, the keyboard would probably not work at all. Moreover, I disassembled and dried the keyboard, and I saw that it was a simple membrane keyboard, and there were not much in it that could be damaged by water in the keystroke sensing part.

Recently I tried once again to investigate the issue. It was strange that just a few keys were not working, while the keyboard was cleaned and dried inside-out.

The keyboard had inside two plastic sheets with printed conductive tracks, separated by an isolating layer with holes at the positions of the keyboard keys. When a key was pressed, the conductive tracks from the two sheets were making contact.

I soon noticed that all the keys that were not responding were found on the same conductive track from the lower layer. Surprisingly, there were one more key on this track that *was* responding.

I bought a [Circuit Scribe](https://circuitscribe.com/) pen and repaired the conductive track between the responding and the non-responding keys, and also added a conductive track between the two keys on the reverse side of the lower layer (it had small holes in it). Now all the keys are working again.

[image]

**My question is:** what are the chemical or the physical processes that damaged the conductive tracks printed on plastic after the water got into the keyboard, while the more sophisticated parts were intact? Is it really hard to make those tracks more resistant to water?

Comment: "*It was very strange to me, since I guessed that if some important element was damaged, the keyboard would probably not work at all.*" Well it wouldn't be if you understood how a keyboard works. I don't know why you say you doubt it was based on experience. I had 5 keyboards die the same way and each time a few drops of water got between the membrane on some specific keys and left some crap behind which affected specific keys connected to that wire network. You could go in and pull out pieces of residue and it would work again for a while but eventually stop working again.

Comment: @DKNguyen, those answers were not specific enough. I was expecting that someone who knows how the damage happens would point me to the problem with the conductive tracks and maybe explain how the residues or whatever else breaks the tracks.

Comment: The preamble in your post essentially boils down to "my problem turned out to not be the same problem that others normally run into so everything they said was with nothing but lies". That's the issue with your post.

Comment: @DKNguyen, i am still in doubt.

Comment: *However, those answers were mostly some "general nonsense" about how sensitive electronics are, how water can contain residues if it is not distilled, and so on.* this has got the qualifications of a rant about getting bad information on a previous question. So, if you are going to say these things then you should link to that previous question.

Comment: @Andyaka, my previous question was closed. The answers I got there hardly offered me any new information in addition to "water is bad for electronics". I am reposting the question after having narrowed down the issue.

Comment: The original post should still be available to you. If you deleted it then don't expect anyone here to appreciate some "semi slanderous" comments about a previous question that nobody but you has access to. If you didn't delete it then where is this earlier post?

Comment: @Andyaka, i do not see the post anywhere on my page and i do not remember deleting it. However, it's been more that a year.

Comment: Far easier and cheaper to not mix keyboards with water, wine, beer, milk, whisky, vodka or use them in the bath...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the earlier question the OP refers to in which he says the answers were "general nonsense" is not available. In other words, it is inflammatory to make such suggestions without the evidence of that previous question.

Comment: @Andyaka, do you want me to rewrite the paragraph in question?

Comment: If you remove ships you will be surprised how much water residual under.

Answer (score 4):

The process is called electrolysis, and occurs when conductors with voltage across them are exposed to water, especially water with ionic contaminants.

It's similar to electroplating, and results in the metal being (relatively) rapidly eroded. You can avoid this by removing power immediately and drying the unit out. Unfortunately that's not so easily done when the water wicks between sheets of polyester as are present in a membrane keyboard. A vacuum chamber would probably help, as would warming the product in a chamber with dessicant (though not nearly as fast or as good as the vacuum).

The membrane keyboard probably could be sealed better, but there would be a cost to that and the manufacturer has judged it not to be worth doing. If a glass of wine or single-malt finds its way into a keyboard, it's probably just as easy to replace it with a new one, even most laptop keyboards are made to be easily swapped out.

Comment: The remedy process outlined here is good. Liquids can wick and persist for a long time, giving electrochemistry a chance. **Prompt** action can save a keyboard, or other electronics.